# C error while printing rectangle: Abort trap: 6

Tags: c

I'm trying to use a two dimensional array to print out a rectangle on screen, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int width = 6;
    int hight = 3;
    char array[5][8];

    // Print the rectangle WITHOUT using the array: 
    for(int i = 0; i <= (hight+1); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= (width+1); j++){
            if((i == 0 || j == 0) || ( i == (hight+1) || j == (width+1))){
                printf("A");
                array[j][i] = 'A';
            } else {
                printf("B");
                array[j][i] = 'B';
            }
        }
        printf("\n");  
    }

    // Print the rectangle using the array: 
    printf("\nRectangle from array: \n\n");

    for(int i = 0; i <= (hight+1); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= (width+1); j++){
            printf("%c", array[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
AAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBA
ABBBBBBA
ABBBBBBA
AAAAAAAA

Rectangle from array: 

AAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBA
ABBBBBBA
ABBBBBBA
AAAAAAAA
Abort trap: 6
```

The rectangle is being printed correctly except for the abort trap error, where's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your array dimensions reversed.

The loops have the width as the first dimension, ranging from 0 to 7, but the first dimension has size 5.  You therefore write past the end of the array triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You want:

```
char array[8][5];
```